# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot

I'm getting the error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

The error is pointing to `return ChatRoomTile(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['participants']);`

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, strTitle: "Messages",),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('/UserChats').where('participants',arrayContains: currentUser.receiverName).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
         if(snapshot.hasData){
           return ListView.builder(
             itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return ChatRoomTile(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['participants']);
             //Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID);
            },
           );
         }else{return Text("Loading/Error");}
        },
      ),
      
      //getChatRooms(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchChat()));
        }
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the type of data the StreamBuilder is expecting by declaring it with the type the stream is yielding, like this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('/UserChats').where('participants',arrayContains: currentUser.receiverName).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
     if(snapshot.hasData){
       // rest
     }else{return Text("Loading/Error");}
    },
  ),
```

And then it depends what is you want to display in the ChatroomTile. Like Owczar says, the ChatroomTile takes a String as argument.

Comment: So I tried this and I got The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<String>>'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like `snapshot.data.documents[index].data['participants']` is a `List` and constructor of `ChatRoomTile` accepts only `String`. If I am right this is a list with only one item, try to get the very first item of the list:

`ChatRoomTile((snapshot.data.documents[index].data['participants'] as List<String>).first);`

Comment: I tried adding .toString(); to the end of participants and that worked! I'm also going to try this method and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @Indigo, also try to debug what you have inside `snapshot.data.documents[index].data['participants']` to ensure you have only one element to process. You can even `print(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['participants']);` right before `return ChatRoomTile...`